# nginx if host true with location and root

Tags: nginx

I use `docker` with `nginx` and this is my `app` config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app.me.site;
  return 308 https://$host$uri;
  location .well-known {
    root /var/www/.well-known;
    try_files /$uri /$uri/ /index.html;
  }
  # other configs
}
```

The path is `/var/www/app`.

I also created `/var/www/.well-known` for Let's Encrypt and it is accessible but it's only accessible for `https`.

I need to have an `if` cluse: if URL is `app.me.site/.well-known`, do not use `https`.

I tried to reach this but did not find any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config is not workable because the `return` directive is executed at the `NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE` while proper location selection will be done later at the `NGX_HTTP_FIND_CONFIG_PHASE` (request processing phases are described in the [development guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases)). To fix it you should move that `return` directive to the `location` block (I also suggest to use the `$request_uri` variable instead the normalized `$uri` one):

```
location / {
    # everything not started with the '/.well-known/' prefix will be processed here
    return 308 https://$host$request_uri;
}
location /.well-known/ {
    # do not append '/.well-known' suffix here!
    # (see the difference between 'root' and 'alias' directives)
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```